# pyspark: how to get_json_object for names with spaces (or other weird characters in the name)?

Tags: pyspark, jsonpath

Normally,

`F.get_json_object(name, "$.element_name")`

works fine to extract the `element_name` from a JSON object like this

```
{"element_name" : 1}
```

But what if the name has a space in this? How do I quote the name?

```
{"element name" : 1}
```

this doesn't work obviously

`F.get_json_object(name, "$.elementname")`

Normally, this is not a pyspark specific problem but it seems like pyspark (and maybe java) can have slightly different specs for the jsonpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark, one of the following two should be working: (1) dot-notation `.name` with name excluding any dot `.` or opening bracket `[`; or (2) bracket-notation `['name']` with name excluding any single quote `'` or question-mark `?`, for example:

```
F.get_json_object('name', "$['element name']")
F.get_json_object('name', "$.element name")
```

see below from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L71) with Scala JsonPathParser:

```
// parse `.name` or `['name']` child expressions
def named: Parser[List[PathInstruction]] =
  for {
    name <- '.' ~> "[^\\.\\[]+".r | "['" ~> "[^\\'\\?]+".r <~ "']"
  } yield {
    Key :: Named(name) :: Nil
  }
```

Thus, if the name contains *dot* or *opening bracket*, use `['name']`, if the name contains *single quote* or *question mark*, use `.name`. otherwise you can select either one. more examples of working expressions:

```
F.get_json_object('name', "$.Trader Joe's")
F.get_json_object('name', "$['amazon.com']")
```

Answer (score 1):

For JSON keys that have names that are unfriendly to properties, you'll need to use the indexer syntax.

```
$["element name"]
```

(Single quotes should also work.)