# Spark-Sql, check if nested keys appear in json string and take the values

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, presto

i have a table with three columns, `source_word`  , `target_word`  and `json_col`

```
source_word    target_word     json_col
source_1       target_1        {"source_1":{"method1":[{"w":"target_1"},{"w":"target_3"}]}}
source_2       target_2        {"source_2":{"method2":[{"w":"target_2"},{"w":"target_4"}]}}
```

as you can see, `json_col` contains a nested dict/json in which the first key is the word from the source_word column `source_1`  then followed by the method name such as `method1, method2, ..., methodn`, and finally it has a list of dictionary with `<w, target_word>` schema (`w` is just a literal to indicate that this is a word). I am interested to check if `json_col` contains the source word `source_1` as the key, followed by `method1` and the keyword `target1` is in `method1`. How do I do this in spark SQL?

This is my working presto sql:

```
select 
   source_word, target_word
from
   table
where
    contains(cast(json_extract(json_col, concat('$["', source_word, '"]["method1"]')) as array(json)), 
json_parse(concat('{"w":"', target_word, '"}')))
```

and this is what I came up with in Spark SQL:

```
select 
   source_word, target_word
from
   table
where
   instr(json_col, concat('{"', source_word, '":{"method1"')) > 0
   and instr(json_col, concat('{"w":"', target_word, '"}')) > 0
```

but then I realised the flaw in this sql, where the conditions might be true for both `instr` but the target_word that I am looking for was not coming from `method1`.

ideally, it should take the values from method1, say `[{"w":"target_1"},{"w":"target_3"}]` and see if `{"w":"target_1"}` is in there.

can someone point me to the right direction? thanks!

Comment: hmm, I am wondering why the downvote tho? this probably not useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [get_json_object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#get_json_object) + [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) to convert all target-values of `w` under `method1` to an array of strings and then use [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains) to filter the rows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
   ("source_1", "target_1", """{"source_1":{"method1":[{"w":"target_1"},{"w":"target_3"}]}}"""),
   ("source_2", "target_2", """{"source_2":{"method2":[{"w":"target_2"},{"w":"target_4"}]}}""")
], ["source_word", "target_word", "json_col"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql("""
  SELECT
    source_word, target_word
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    array_contains(
      from_json(get_json_object(json_col, concat("$['",source_word,"'].method1[*].w")), 'array<string>'),
      target_word
    )
""").show()
+-----------+-----------+
|source_word|target_word|
+-----------+-----------+
|   source_1|   target_1|
+-----------+-----------+
```

**Where we do the following:**

1. use `concat("$['",source_word,"'].method1[*].w")` to create JSONPath. for example, we will have `$['source_1'].method1[*].w` for Row-1. **Notice** that for Spark, we must use single quote `'` to enclose *source_word* when using the bracket-notation of the child expression with JSONPath(see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64362680/9510729)), double-quote `"` will not work.
2. use `get_json_object(json_col, ..)` to retrieve a string like `["target_1","target_3"]` for Row-1 or *NULL* for Row-2
3. use `from_json(.., 'array<string>')` to convert the above to an array of strings
4. use `array_contains(.., target_word)` to identify if *target_word* exists in the array

BTW. you can also replace the above `from_json` + `array_contains` with `instr` function to search *target_word* as shown in your code.